Geometric point - definition of Hilbert Scheme
I am trying to fully understand construction around Hilbert Schemes. In paper
Stein Arild Strømme: Elementary Introduction to Representable Functors and Hilbert Schemes, Parameter Spaces, Banach Center Publications, 36, Institute of Mathematics, Polish Academy of Sciences, 179-198, 1996.
he makes heavy use of geometric points. For him, geometric points are, as he defined on page 3, a morphism of schemes $f:T \to X$ where $X$ is a fixed scheme, and $T = \operatorname{Spec}(K)$, for algebraically closed field $K$.
What is not clear here? For any ring $A$, $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is a set of prime ideals of $A$. If $K$ is a field, then $\operatorname{Spec}(K)$ is the set of prime ideals in $K$. All ideals in a field $K$ are $0$ and $K$. They are both prime (technically, $0$ is a prime ideal in every integral domain). Hence $\operatorname{Spec}(K) = \{0,K\}$. So, a morphism of schemes $\operatorname{Spec}(K) \to X$ is actually fully defined by $f(0)$ and $f(K)$. Now, $f(0) = 0$, and so one morphism is a zero morphism, and the other is basically embedding of $K$ (well, if you map a field, then there is no other option, since $\ker(f)$ is ideal in $K$).
Hence, my point reads: if I am not very mistaken, there are only two geometric points for any scheme $X$: one is zero and the other is the inclusion of field $K$. Now what would make sense is to include all algebraically closed fields that could be embedded in $X$ somehow... but I am not sure. So, how is this exactly an important object?

Prime ideals are by definition proper. So $K$ itself is not a prime ideal of $K$ and hence $\operatorname{Spec}(K) = {(0)}$.

To respond to your actual question: a morphism of schemes is more than just a map on points---it also includes a map of sheaves. While the spectrum of every field consists of just one point, their structure sheaves can be very different, as the global sections of the structure sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec}(K)$ is $K$ itself.

thankies @ViktorVaughn!
